# My problem is about wechat pages jump ,when i want jump to one page ,it always flash another pages

Tags: wechat

pages order is shelf->photo->refer->photos->shelf.but when photos->shelf,the refer page always flash.

```
wx.navigateTo({
   url: '../shelf?rstoreId=' + this.data.rstoreId,
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that there are `'shelf.wxml','shelf.wxss' and 'shelf.js'` in your 'shelf' folder.

Use **'../shelf/shelf'** instead of **'../shelf'**

```js
wx.navigateTo({
   url: '../shelf/shelf?rstoreId=' + this.data.rstoreId,
 })
```